Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? can't activate sqlite3 (VERSION GEM) already activated sqlite3-Version
I'm trying to upload a localhost server with my application's rails, but I'm having this problem with my sqlite3 gem
Infos
Ruby version: 3.2.0
Rails version: 7.1.3.4
SqliteGem: 2.0
Version show in Gem error: sqlite3 1.4
rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 7.1.3.4 application starting in development http://localhost:3000
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
[2024-06-05 14:04:59] INFO  WEBrick 1.8.1
[2024-06-05 14:04:59] INFO  ruby 3.2.0 (2022-12-25) [x86_64-linux]
[2024-06-05 14:04:59] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=380133 port=3000
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jun/2024:14:05:02 -03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 0
- -> /
[2024-06-05 14:05:02] ERROR LoadError: Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? can't activate sqlite3 (~> 1.4), already activated sqlite3-2.0.2-x86_64-linux-gnu. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:237:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
        <internal:/home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        <internal:/home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.15/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_handler.rb:333:in `resolve_pool_config'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_handler.rb:134:in `establish_connection'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `establish_connection'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:304:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:97:in `class_eval'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:97:in `block in execute_hook'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:87:in `with_execution_control'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:92:in `execute_hook'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:78:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:77:in `each'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:77:in `run_load_hooks'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:338:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
        <internal:/home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        <internal:/home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.15/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.4/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `run'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:29:in `before'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:426:in `block in make_lambda'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:202:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:707:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:706:in `catch'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:706:in `block in default_terminator'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:203:in `block in halting'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:598:in `block in invoke_before'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:598:in `each'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:598:in `invoke_before'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:109:in `run_callbacks'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:129:in `run'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:125:in `run!'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:78:in `block in run!'
        <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.3.4/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:75:in `run!'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.1.3.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.1.3.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:25:in `call'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/bundler/gems/rack-8d7c029ed113/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:114:in `call'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.1.3.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:141:in `call'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:536:in `call'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-cors-2.0.2/lib/rack/cors.rb:102:in `call'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rackup-2.1.0/lib/rackup/handler/webrick.rb:111:in `service'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/webrick-1.8.1/lib/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/webrick-1.8.1/lib/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
        /home/elton/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/webrick-1.8.1/lib/webrick/server.rb:310:in `block in start_thread'

My gemfile, I already set sqlite3 updated version, but it shows the error anyway
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '3.2.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 7.1'


gem 'rack-cors'


gem 'mailgun-ruby', '~>1.2.5'

gem 'rack-timeout'

gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.12'



group :development, :test do
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'colorize'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'bundler-audit'
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
  # Can be configured to work on production as well see: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/README.md
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data'

gem "importmap-rails", "~> 1.1"

gem "hotwire-rails", "~> 0.1.3"
gem "tailwindcss-rails", "~> 2.6"
gem 'rack', git: 'https://github.com/rack/rack'

gem "rackup", "~> 2.1" 

# Use Puma as the app server
gem "passenger", "~> 6.0"

gem "recaptcha", "~> 5.16"

gem 'sqlite3', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.2'

I need to fix this problem by setting a single sqlite3 gem

Have you run bundle install?

The error appears when activating sqlite3, using rails s, apparently there is another sqlite from another version running

Can't use sqlite3 v2 because db adapters explicitly limit the version:
gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.4"

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.1.3.4/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb#L14
Best explanation that I could find for this:

lean on rubygems to provide error messages about missing gems

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/146474256cf2f09f9706980032688b2c7d484e24
